# Typescript - Use result of one interface generic method as input for another interface method

Tags: typescript, methods, properties, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a generic interface that will reuse result of one interface method as an input of another interface methods.

Here is the most basic example of what I am trying to achieve

```
interface BasicProps<T> {
  input: T;
}

interface TransformProps<T, O> {
  transform: (input: T) => O;
  render: <R extends ReturnType<this['transform']>>(input: R) => any;
}

type TProps<T, O> = BasicProps<T> & TransformProps<T, O>;

function test<T, O>(props: TProps<T, O>) {
  return props.render(props.transform(props.input));
}

const testData = {
  name: 'Jon',
  age: 37,
  ts: true,
  nested: {
    test: 1,
    best: true
  }
};

const testResult = test({
  input: testData,
  transform: (input) => input.nested,
  render: (input) => input.test,
});
```

Everything seems fine until I want to access `input` inside `render` method where it seems that `R extends unknown` despite the fact that it is properly inferred when checking `render` method type which have `R extends { test: number, best: boolean }`.

My question is how to achieve type inferring the way that TS will accept `input.test` inside render method and will infer `boolean` as `render` result type.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM7AQBSgewAcMAeAFQD5kBvAKGWVEIFcwAuZMgbloF9baoSLEQoyUOCAwx8UALZ4ipMgBpkAeSp0GYCVJnyOACiasOZAJTIAvFXU8GUCCAAm0DiQBKyCAA9IrhjInhBgzFAgZACehBAkYAAWwBgA2gDkupLSsnJpALoUFCYgLOzBVrbIklE8-LRgMWKKxORqmjZomNjNylQAZJx62fI9rRoUPLQwzCAIYMD4IMiQGGBjmkaEBMTmo6rjVtrITmERyFtKAHROrtCb2xiXmfo591emYBYWtQIIi6vLCCrAAicDAcA6RxAcDkEA4aQAUos0ip6FUAOZw5AAZgA7KidBgOLpmBACcgQEDIC4OEcdFSOABGckMABGDOWUFJaP4vEmfykYEBqxCGGYABshdZhWAjNRGCUzDLQeC1M9hnIOB8bFQPpdKasIC41Dc3FAtYqpbrLU8qcheN8gA)

Comment: It is strange. Your example works if `render` does not return anything. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/N7KMPN)

Comment: For some unknown for me reason Typescript cannot infer return type of `transform` inside call of `test`. To help Typescript infer it use `const testResult = test<typeof testData, typeof testData.nested>({ input: testData, transform: input => input.nested, render: input => input.test });`

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks, that's a good clue!

Comment: @Leemellaret unfortunately manually specifying generics is not an option for me

Comment: @ChristopherKalkhoff I believe you can create an issue